# Can't make JUnit work (assertThat/hasItem)

Tags: java, junit, junit4, hamcrest

I've just created a dummy Maven project:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.loki2302</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-test-app</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>junit-test-app</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I have the only test in this project:

```
package com.loki2302;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Test; // for @Test annotation
import static org.junit.Assert.*; // for assertThat()
import static org.junit.matchers.JUnitMatchers.*; // for hasItem()

public class AppTest {  
    @Test
    public void sillyTest() {
        List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(123, 456);
        assertThat(list, hasItem(123));
    }   
}
```

When I run `mvn clean test`, it says:

```
D:\junit-test-app>mvn clean test
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building junit-test-app 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ junit-test-app ---
[INFO] Deleting D:\junit-test-app\target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:resources (default-resources) @ junit-test-app ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\junit-test-app\src\main\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ junit-test-app ---
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to D:\junit-test-app\target\classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:testResources (default-testResources) @ junit-test-app ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\junit-test-app\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ junit-test-app ---
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to D:\junit-test-app\target\test-classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] \junit-test-app\src\test\java\com\loki2302\AppTest.java:[15,19] error: cannot find symbol
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.512s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Jul 11 10:38:06 MSD 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/107M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project junit-test-app: Compilation failure
[ERROR] \junit-test-app\src\test\java\com\loki2302\AppTest.java:[15,19] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Maven version:

```
D:\junit-test-app>mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.0.3 (r1075438; 2011-02-28 20:31:09+0300)
Maven home: D:\apache-maven-3.0.3\bin\..
Java version: 1.7.0, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1251
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

Java version:

```
D:\junit-test-app>java -version
java version "1.7.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0-b147)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 21.0-b17, mixed mode)
```

How do I make it work?

**Update**

Fixed imports for `Assert` and `JUnitMatchers`, updated output for `mvn clean test`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have:

```
import org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.matchers.JUnitMatchers.*;
```

When what you want is:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.junit.matchers.JUnitMatchers.*;
```

Comment: Really good point, such a silly mistake. But it still doesn't work, please see the updated question.

Comment: @loki2302: Hmm. I'm typing on my phone right now, so I can't test easily, but IIRC the default source version used by the maven-compiler-plugin is pretty ancient. Does it work if you [configure the compiler plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html) to use source version 1.7?

Comment: @loki2302: Also, I appreciate the checkmark, but if your problem really isn't solved, you probably shouldn't mark any answer as accepted yet -- that will just discourage others from answering the question.

Comment: I've cleaned up my local Maven cache, restarted machine and then it worked. So, it looks like there was only 1 problem from the code standpoint you mentioned. Thanks!